# How can I set a value to a Rhino Mocked object?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, rhino-mocks, rhino-mocks-3.5

I have a scenario like this:

```
 form = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IAddAddressForm>();
 mediator = new AddAddressMediator(form);
```

The mediator is the real object under test and needs to be able to set values for the "form" object.

But the only way I can see to set values for the form object is like this:

```
  form.Stub(x=>x.FirstName).Return(item.FirstName)
```

I don't want to be doing that in my real code.

Am I missing the point of mocks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Stubs](http://ayende.com/Wiki/(S(lx2onhqvwgxbx145bol1zdbm))/Rhino+Mocks+-+Stubs.ashx) have built in support for property behaviour.  In cases where you aren't using stubs, you can use the [PropertyBehaviour()](http://ayende.com/Wiki/(S(atblwmbdmua30v555jvmhx45))/Default.aspx?Page=Rhino+Mocks+Properties&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1) method for a similar effect.

Within the mediator, you should be using the `form` object normally -- it should not know that it has been handed a fake object.

This code:

```
form.Stub(x=>x.FirstName).Return(item.FirstName)
```

should not be in your real object, but may be part of your *test* to set up the expectations for how you will use your mock object.

**Edit:**

From what you've provided, I can't judge whether you're "missing the point of mocks".  The essential purpose is to provide a way to test code that has dependencies in isolation from those dependencies.  Have a look at Martin Fowler's essay "[Mocks Aren't Stubs](http://www.martinfowler.com/articles/mocksArentStubs.html)", and the Usage Guidance section of the [Rhino Mocks documentation](http://ayende.com/Wiki/Rhino+Mocks+3.5.ashx).

Comment: Sweet Answer!  Thank you so much (I wish I could vote you up twice!)